# What's wrong with this date behavior in C#?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

If I output a formatted date as follows:

`DateTime.Parse("2010-06-02T15:26:37.789 +01:00").ToString("HH:mm:sszzz")`

I get the expected result:

`15:26:37+01:00`

However, if I parse the same date, convert to UTC and output with the same format as follows:

`DateTime.Parse("2010-06-02T15:26:37.789 +01:00").ToUniversalTime().ToString("HH:mm:sszzz")`

I get this:

`14:26:37+01:00`

Now those two dates, the local and UTC versions, should be exactly the same but the outputted text represents two different times.

Why is this?

### EDIT

To clarify, I expected the time in UTC to be 14:26:37 as the DST element is removed by UTC. I didn't expect it to still have an offset. The two above times are not equivalent, whereas 15:26:37+***01:00*** and 14:26:37+***00:00*** are.

Comment: Okay, I fail to get it. You parse a DateTime with a Timezone Offset of +1 and ask why exactly this amount is removed by .ToUniversalTime()? What am I missing?

Comment: @Benjamin: the result should be "+0:00" if it really were UTC.

Comment: @Stefan: Thanks, maybe I'm wrong, but http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#zzzSpecifier says (Quote following): With DateTime  values, the "zzz" custom format specifier represents the signed offset of the local operating system's time zone from UTC, measured in hours and minutes. It does not reflect the value of an instance's DateTime.Kind property. For this reason, the "zzz" format specifier is not recommended for use with DateTime  values.

Comment: @Benjamin: so put this into an answer, because this is the answer to the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, so now as an answer: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#zzzSpecifier) explains "zzz" like this:

> With DateTime  values, the "zzz"
>   custom format specifier represents the
>   signed offset **of the local operating
>   system's time zone from UTC**, measured
>   in hours and minutes. It does not
>   reflect the value of an instance's
>   DateTime.Kind property. For this
>   reason, the "zzz" format specifier is
>   not recommended for use with DateTime 
>   values.

Empasis mine.
English's not my native language, but I read that as "zzz" being the machine's offset, not related to the DateTime value at all. So - yes, it will be the same..

Comment: +1: English *is* my native language, and you are reading that correctly.

Comment: +1, that's exactly the problem here. One more reason to hate dates and times.

Comment: That explains it. Your answer is correct but the usage seems a little silly!

Answer (score 0):

Your locale's timezone is probably UTC+1. Check the result after .ToUniversalTime(), it should be 14:26 (UTC+1-1 = UTC).

Comment: My user's time zone is UTC+1 but why does this matter? My point is that a UTC time should have no offset. Ever. Unless I'm missing some point?

Answer (score 0):

June is in the daylight saving period. UTC does not do daylight savings.

Strangely... or not. If you change the month from June to Jan it will be the same!

As I said daylight savings!!!